# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: php

I am getting the following error when clicking on a category named Test

FastCGI sent in stderr:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/mydomain/public_html/app/functions/fn.catalog.php on line 736" while reading response header from upstream, client: 24.xx.xx.xx, server: www.mydomain.com, request: "GET /test-page-313/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://www.mydomain....lesale-towels/"

My 736 Line is as follows

In my `php.ini` I've already increase the `memory_limit` to = `1G`

```
for ($qty = $min_qty; $qty <= $max_qty; $qty += $product['qty_step']) {
    $qty_content[] = $qty;
}
```

Comment: And how does the `$max_qty` or `$qty` change in that loop? At what point you would reach an end-condition?

Comment: Probably 0 or undefined - `$qty += $product['qty_step']`  .   Debugging step 1: find out what values your code is using.  An echo is one way.  You probably have no error checking for the values, which is bad.

Comment: As suggested above, can you do: `print "\$min_qty='$min_qty'<br />\$max_qty='$max_qty'<br />\$product['qty_step'] = $product['qty_step']";`

Comment: Did you restart the web-server after changing the ini setting?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the values of `$min_qty`, `$max_qty`, and `$product['qty_step']` before the for loop. Without that, there isn't enough information here to determine the exact problem.

Comment: And I agree with @Don'tPanic; note that an array of integers / numbers is not very likely to lead to the memory usage you are describing...

Comment: Also, please use var_dump or something like that to determine the real values - not just what you think they should be at that point.

Comment: Basically you have an endless loop there. Even if you add 1TB to the server, it won't fix it.

Comment: Maybe it's not an endless loop but variables like `$min_qty = 0; $max_qty = 400000; $product = array("qty_step" => 0.001);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possibilities :

- `$product['qty_step']` doesn't contain a number
- There are two many steps in your loop that makes your program creating many entries in the `$qty_content` array.

For example, if you have:

```
$min_qty = 0;
$max_qty = 400000;
$product = array("qty_step" => 0.001);
$qty_content = [];

// The loop
for ($qty = $min_qty; $qty <= $max_qty; $qty += $product['qty_step']) {
    $qty_content[] = $qty;
}
```

The program will try to make up to 400000000 entries in the array, which takes so much memory that PHP can't handle it. So it throws the error you've got. As someones said in your question's comments, try to debug the content of all variables, for example:

```
var_dump(
  array('qty' => $qty,
    'min_qty' => $min_qty,
    'max_qty' => $max_qty,
    'product["qty_step"]' => $product['qty_step'])
);
```

And see what you get. In all cases, this error means you're taking too much memory, so you must reduce the loop's iterations by increasing `$product['qty_step']` or reducing the difference between `$min_qty` and `$max_qty`.